# Knockout: search for zero in an observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of lines and I want to set a Boolean flag depending on whether any of them has the WeekHrs property set to zero.
So I have this code which works. However it is inefficient as the ForEach loop should break once the flag is set to false.
So there must be a better way of doing this?

```
self.isFull = function () {
    var isFull = true;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Lines(),
        function (line) {
            if (line.WeekHrs() === 0) {
                isFull = false;
            }
        });
    return isFull;
},
```

I looked at the other utilities but I can't work out how to use them for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers implement [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which can return at any point. `every` returns when the test method returns `false`, some returns when the test method returns `true`.

```
self.isFull = function() {
  return self.Lines().every(function(line) {
    return line.WeekHrs() !== 0;
  });
};

self.isFull = function () {
  return !self.Lines().some(function (line) {
    return line.WeekHrs() === 0;
  });
}
```

Note that you could also use this method in a `computed`, if needed:

```
self.isFullComputed = ko.pureComputed(self.isFull)
```

---

Edit for completeness: As suggested in the comments, you could of course use a regular `for` loop:

```
self.isFull = function() {
  var allLines = self.Lines(),
      length = allLines.length,
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    if (line.WeekHrs() === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};
```

Additionally, you could implement the suggested [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill) if you need to support < IE9.

Comment: And if you need to support older browsers, you can just bypass utility stuff like `some` and `arrayForEach` and just use a bog standard `for` loop.  Just because the newer methods are there, doesn't mean you have to use them when the older ways are more appropriate :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I've included the `for` equivalent you suggested. Note that `some` has been in the spec for some time now (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17). Personally, I believe we shouldn't be too afraid to adopt the newer features...

Comment: Oh absolutely - the newer features do provide for much neater code.  But they can get in the way sometimes too.  Just relooking at the OPs code and your `some` example - I may have too many double negatives going on in my head, but I'm not sure your code matches the original? (brain is hurting too much trying to think about it at the mo!)

Comment: Good catch; I had swapped `true` and `false`. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: In your answer using "some" only the second example works. However it does work so thank you very much!

Comment: OK, I can now see you are using every and when you do that then the first example works as well. Thank you for that.